# У меня есть spinner, я хочу передать значение, например, первого элемента, в другое activity. Как это сделать?

Tags: kotlin, android-spinner

У меня есть spinner:

```
val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.categories_spinner)
            val vehicle = arrayOf(
                "Автокраны",
                ...
            )
            val adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_spinner, vehicle)

            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner)
            spinner.adapter = adapter
```

Я хочу выбрать первый элемент и сохранить его в строку, по типу `var selectedItem: String = parent.getItemAtPosition (position) as String`

```
if (position == 0) {
                image_check.setOnClickListener {
                    mkVehicleAutocranes()
                    mViewModel.mkVehicleCompletedEvent.observe(this@AddVehicleActivity, Observer {
                        startActivity(Intent(this@AddVehicleActivity, ListAutocranes::class.java))
                    })
                }
            }
```

После в другом activity показать выбранный элемент. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю то вам необходимо передать значение Title из Spinner.

```
String title = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()
```

Потом вам необходимо создать интент и положить в бандл ваши данные

```
Intent intent =  new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(YOUR_KEY, title);
startActivity(intent);
```